# Skobbler "Route cannot be calculated" error message

Tags: android, skmaps

I am implementing custom turn-by-turn navigation using SKobbler. I am getting a message "Route cannot be calculated" at times. But, the source and the destination coordinates are correct. I tried the same coordinates in google maps. It provides me the route. I don't know what is wrong in calculating route in SKobbler. Please provide me some suggestions to get rid of this issue.

Comment: Can you add some start & end coordinates that give errors? Please also add the code you are using for routing (SKRouteSettings)? Could it be that the internet connection is to blame? (you can test this by making the map available on-board and see if the message still appears)

Comment: I've also seen the same error but with the iOS SDK (v2.5). What I noticed is that routes with destinations that are close by are computed correctly (so California), but routes to NV, CO, NY all fail. The error I get is "ROUTE_CANNOT_BE_CALCULATED" but when I proxy all web calls the app makes through Charles, I see that a call to the Skobbler API is never contacted for any routing calls. The Android version of our implementation issues out calls to the Skobbler API for each route request and succeeds with the same routes. Both have routeConnectionMode set to Hybrid. Thoughts?

Comment: I also forgot to mention in my comment above, that if I set the routeConnectionMode to Online while testing, then I get the INTERNAL_ERROR SKRoutingErrorCode response and no calls as shown to be made to the API service either. Is there another set of settings that may affect if an online call is made other than routeConnectionMode within the routesettings? Thanks!

Comment: One last thing: I can confirm that the internet is setup correctly on the test device, because I do see other API calls being made to Skobbler to update things like the map .json file when the app first opens and also calls to update traffic and incident information periodically when the map view is showing. Thanks!

Comment: @Ando, do you have any thoughts on my comments above? Thanks for any help!